# Can I add a monochome scalable custom icon to the iOS navigation bar?

Tags: ios, icons, uinavigationbar

iOS' [Template Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html) cannot cover all necessary icons, so I need to add a custom one to my navigation bar (a "···" more icon).

Now is there a way to give iOS a monochome, scalable icon file that I can tint in a maintainable way (e.g. same color as text) and do not need to generate bitmaps for?

OS X uses PDFs for that when you want to use them as a tray icon, such that OS X can change color of the icon depending on bright/dark color theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

If you want `tintColor` for all your `navigationItems`, you can use

```
let sharedApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

---

#### TL;DR:

This is possible because from `iOS 7`, `UIImage` has a `renderingMode` property.

> Create a version of this image with the specified rendering mode. By default, images have a rendering mode of UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic.

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public func imageWithRenderingMode(renderingMode: UIImageRenderingMode) -> UIImage
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public var renderingMode: UIImageRenderingMode { get }
```

About `renderingMode`:

> Images are created with UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic by default. An image with this mode is interpreted as a template image or an original image based on the context in which it is rendered. For example, navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and segmented controls automatically treat their foreground images as templates, while image views and web views treat their images as originals. You can use UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate to force your image to always be rendered as a template or UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to force your image to always be rendered as an original.

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public enum UIImageRenderingMode : Int {

    case Automatic // Use the default rendering mode for the context where the image is used
    case AlwaysOriginal // Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template
    case AlwaysTemplate // Always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color information
}
```

We need not change the rendering mode of the navigationItem image because, navigation bars controls automatically treat their foreground images as templates.

If we want, using `imageWithRenderingMode()` method we can change the rendering mode of any UIImage to have this functionality e.g.

```
UIImage(named: "settings")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
```

For scaling you could refer to the `resizableImageWithCapInsets()` method of `UIImage`

For more info, please see this Ray Wenderlich tutorial by  **Essan Parto** 
[UIAppearance Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial)

**Update**:

[image]

See this above image. It is only 10x10 pixels.
The image may be tiny, but iOS knows exactly how to use it to draw as it’s been pre-sliced and is resizable.

Example

```
let controlBackground = UIImage(named: "controlBackground")?
    .imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    .resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3))
```

The top, left, bottom, right corners are untouched and middle portion of the image will be starched. With this tiny image, you can make a big rectangle keeping image corner intact.

You can also slice Using `xcode` right into `.xcassets`.
[image]

Comment: When using `resizableImageWithCapInsets()` I have to provide a 3x PNG and scale it down, right? There is no way to provide an SVG or PDF?

Comment: @SimonWarta I think you can't use SVG or PDF as image resource in xcode. 3x  2x pngs have different purpose. Only iPhone 6s Plus and iPhone 6 Plus use 3x pngs. iPad2 and iPad mini use 1x pngs. All other use 2x pngs. I'll update my answer with an example of `resizableImageWithCapInsets()'

Comment: @SimonWarta answer updated. You can open the tutorial link I mentioned. At the end of the tutorial you'll find the source code download link.

Comment: @SimonWarta I was wrong about PDF. See this http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/ for 3rd party SVG see this https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit